# How to flash boot partition on BBB?

Tags: embedded, beaglebone-black

I am trying to restore a bricked BBB device. Booting Debian from the SD card works fine (thanks to http://thethingsystem.com/dev/Bootstrapping-the-BeagleBone-Black-with-Debian.html ). Once the device is booted, I try to copy the Debian image to the emmc partition:

```
$ xz -cd debian-wheezy-7.2-armhf-3.8.13-bone30.img.xz > /dev/mmcblk1
```

This works but the boot partition is 100% full.

However, I need more space on that partition as I want to install a custom boot image with a display driver support (the Debian image from http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-67958?ICID=BBB-feature-viewpanel )

So, once the BBB has booted with the SD card, I try to resize the boot image with:

```
$ [sudo mkfs.msdos -F 32 /dev/sdc1 -n LABEL1]
mkfs.msdos 2.11 (12 Mar 2005)

$ [sudo mkfs.ext3 -L LABEL2 /dev/sdc2]
```

from https://code.google.com/p/beagleboard/wiki/LinuxBootDiskFormat

- How could I make the device booting from mmcblk1p1 ? Can I copy over the image from the SD card, how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Check [here](http://derekmolloy.ie/write-a-new-image-to-the-beaglebone-black/)

Comment: thanks - I need to try the "flasher" image then, interestingly in the comment threads is a section about flashing from a running sd card image: https://github.com/RobertCNelson/tools/tree/master/scripts

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, with the flasher image, all steps are shown how to partition and copy an image to the embedded flash memory:

```
Erasing: /dev/mmcblk1 complete
-----------------------------
Writing bootloader to [/dev/mmcblk1]
dd if=/opt/backup/uboot/MLO of=/dev/mmcblk1 count=1 seek=1 conv=notrunc bs=128k
-----------------------------
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
73516 bytes (74 kB) copied, 0.0287943 s, 2.6 MB/s
-----------------------------
dd if=/opt/backup/uboot/u-boot.img of=/dev/mmcblk1 count=2 seek=1 conv=notrunc bs=384k
-----------------------------
1+1 records in
1+1 records out
393496 bytes (393 kB) copied, 0.212742 s, 1.8 MB/s
-----------------------------
Formatting: /dev/mmcblk1
Checking that no[   46.657434]  mmcblk1: unknown partition table
-one is using this disk right now ...
OK

Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 119808 cylinders, 4 heads, 16[   46.673010]  mmcblk1: p1 p2
 sectors/track

sfdisk: ERROR: sector 3069486077 does not have an msdos signature
 /dev/mmcblk1: unrecognized partition table type
Old situation:
No partitions found
New situation:
Units = mebibytes of 1048576 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start   End    MiB    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk1p1   *     1     96     96      98304    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk1p2        97   3743   3647    3734528   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk1p3         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
/dev/mmcblk1p4         0      -      0          0    0  Empty
Successfully wrote the new partition table

Re-reading the partition table ...

If you created or changed a DOS partition, /dev/foo7, say, then use dd(1)
to zero the first 512 bytes:  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/foo7 bs=512 count=1
(See fdisk(8).)
mkfs.vfat -F 16 /dev/mmcblk1p1 -n BEAGLEBONE
-----------------------------
mkfs.vfat 3.0.13 (30 Jun 2012)
-----------------------------
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk1p2 -L rootfs
-----------------------------
mke2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
ext2fs_check_if_mount: Can't check if filesystem is mounted due to missing mtab file while determining whether /dev/mmcblk1p2 is mounted.
Discarding device blocks: done
Filesystem label=rootfs
pm:Downloads pmu$ disutil list
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
233856 inodes, 933632 blocks
46681 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=956301312
29 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8064 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

-----------------------------
Formatting: /dev/mmcblk1 complete
-----------------------------
Copying: /dev/mmcblk0p1 -> /dev/mmcblk1p1
rsync: /boot/uboot/ -> /tmp/boot/
rsync: ignore the % values when shown as they are not accurate...
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
233856 inodes, 933632 blocks
46681 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=956301312
29 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8064 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

-----------------------------
Formatting: /dev/mmcblk1 complete
-----------------------------
Copying: /dev/mmcblk0p1 -> /dev/mmcblk1p1
rsync: /boot/uboot/ -> /tmp/boot/
```